# Run database query based on selection in QGIS

Tags: postgis, qgis-3

I'm trying to figure out the best approach to achieve the following:

1. A user selects a single or group of features.
2. Option to access a popup box with a set of dropdowns populated by DB query.
3. The user saves, and a database query is run.
4. PostGIS layers are refreshed.

One thing to note is that the PostGIS layer the user will be selecting features from is a view query, so the update needs to be made to different tables.

Could anyone point me in the right direction of what to research/look at?  I'm wondering if I would have to write a plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Without coding a plugin (although it can do exactly what is wanted in terms of algorithm, query and design), I think it's possible to achieve what you want with the QGIS interface for just one feature selected. For a group of features, I think the only way (for have a dialog with comboboxes that update selected datas) is a PyQGIS plugin.

If you want to develop a QGIS plugin, take a look at useful plugins :

- Plugin Builder (for create with few clicks base files for a working plugin)
- Plugin Reloader (reload the developed plugin without quit QGIS)

For software :

- Qt Creator for edit the .ui dialog interface file (software package with QGIS installation)
- Qt Assistant for documentation of Qt object classes

For code :

- Python 3 and [QGIS Python API](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/)
- PyQt (for connection with database, I recommand you to look at QSqlQuery Qt class.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I ended up just writing the plugin!